# Monitoring unix system performance with java

Tags: java, performance, unix, aix

I want to build a simple application that will show performance status of a remote unix system.

The idea is, using some server side program to gather performance status data periodically on the unix system and send those data to client via websocket and draw some cool chart using html5 canvas api.

I am using AIX 7.1, my question is what's the best way to gather performance status data periodically using java, and this action itself should not have an impact on system performance.

Note, I can ony choose java as the language for the server side.

Comment: Voted to move to superuser, as the core of the question is: How to get performance data on AIX?

Comment: Shouldn't that be a serverfault question?

Comment: There are tools for that much better suited for the task - SNMP?

Comment: [OperatingSystemMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html) is all Java provides. If these information are enough for you, you don’t even need to implement something on the server side, just a running JVM allowing JMX connections will provide that. So all you need then is to implement the client.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it need to be in Java? There are readily available solutions for Host Monitoring. One of the earliest,easiest and opensource one is Ganglia http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/‎